# Bash: how to get the complete substring of a match in a string?

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8, grep, iso-8859-1

I have a TXT file, which is shipped from a Windows machine and is encoded in **ISO-8859-1**. My Qt application is supposed to read this file but `QString` supports only UTF-8 (I want to avoid working with `QByteArray`). I've been sturggling to find a way to do that in Qt so I decided to write a small script that does the conversion for me. I have no problem writing it for exactly my case but I would like to make it more general - for all ISO-8859 encoding.

So far I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output=$(file -i $1)

# If the output contains any sort of ISO-8859 substring
if echo "$output" | grep -qi "ISO-8859"; then
  # Retrieve actual encoding
  encoding=...
  # run iconv to convert
  iconv -f $encoding $1 -t UTF-8 -o $1
else
  echo "Text file not encoded in ISO-8859"
fi
```

The part that I'm struggling with is how to get the complete substring that has been successfully mached in the `grep` command.

Let's say I have the file `helloworld.txt` and it's encoded in ISO-8859-15. In this case

```
$~: ./fixEncodingToUtf8 helloworld.txt
stations.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-15
```

will be the `output` in the terminal. Internally the `grep` finds the `iso-8859` (since I use the `-i` flag it processes the input in a case-insensitive way). At this point the script needs to "extract" the whole substring namely not just `iso-8859` but `iso-8859-15` and store it inside the `encoding` variable to use it later with `iconv` (which is case insensitive (phew!) when it comes to the name of the encodings).

**NOTE:** The script above can be extended even further by simply retrieving the value that follows `charset` and using it for the `encoding`. However this has one huge flaw - what if the input file has an encoding that has a larger character set than UTF-8 (simple example: UTF-16 and UTF-32)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this case it is rather pointless…

```
$ file --brief --mime-encoding "$1"
iso-8859-15
```

---

**file** manual

```
-b, --brief
        Do not prepend filenames to output lines (brief mode).
...
--mime-type, --mime-encoding
        Like -i, but print only the specified element(s).
```

Comment: :O I've missed this argument while reading through the documentation... **faceplam**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` or `awk` to get at this:

awk:

```
encoding=$(echo $output | awk -F"=" '{print $2}')
```

cut:

```
encoding=$(echo $output | cut -d"=" -f2)
```

I think you could just feed this over to your `iconv` command directly and reduce your script to:

```
iconv -f $(file $1 | cut -d"=" -f2) -t UTF-8 file
```

Comment: Awesome. So basically you split the contents of `output` at the `=` and get the second half. The only question that remains is: is the output from `file -i $1` guaranteed to end on `...=ENCODING` or is it possible for something else to be added after the encoding?

Comment: No. I don't think it's all guaranteed from what I've seen spit out from the `file` command. Check out `man file` though and there may be a way to force the output of the command to only dump the character set. You may run into some oddball edge cases though.

Comment: I've seen a lot of examples and all had the encoding at the end (for this particular call). However a more general solution would be appreciated. I was unable to find anything in the `man` pages regarding this matter.

Comment: It's kind of odd. With `file` `-i` flag on a UTF-16LE encoded document I get `test3.txt: application/octet-stream` so... it's kind of a toss up. I guess you could capture that `encoding` variable and test to see that it's set. If it isn't then perhaps deal with it as an edge case seperately. I'm not sure there is a  one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or using bash features like below

```
$ str="stations.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-15"
$ echo "${str#*=}"
iso-8859-15
```

To save in variable

```
$ myvar="${str#*=}"
```

Comment: Cool. See my comment under @JNevill 's answer.